# What is meant by Skype Integration in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: skype

I noticed that I still don't get toast notifications for new messages. (EDIT: Changing my chat status from **invisible** to **available** suddenly let off a flood of toasts from Skype.)

I tried setting up an account in the same place where you can add Facebook, Twitter, etc., but there's nothing for Skype.

I've installed the app.

It doesn't seem integrated, so am I missing something or what is meant by integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at [Skype garage blog](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/windows_phone/) and there are some mentions there: (we are talking about Windows Phone 8 version of the app)

For Preview 2.0 (12th November 2012):

> you'll get all of the Skype basics in the new, modern design along with many of the new features such as integration with the People Hub and a combined contact list with buddies from Windows Live Messenger. Additionally, you'll start receiving some call and message notifications - even when the app is closed and in the background.

For Preview 2.1 (2nd January 2013):

> In this release we have worked on improving reliability and performance of the application, especially around background notifications and calling.
>
> We have also temporarily disabled the People Hub integration as it was causing issues with device stability. We are working with the Windows Phone team to resolve the issue and to enable the integration again in a future release.

The main thing here is that it is only **preview**. But they are evidently working on it, so just follow their blog or wait for future updates.

And to answer your question completely - what is meant by integration?:
The main thing in integration is the behavior when the Skype is in background.

From phonearena.com:

> Windows Phone users won't have their Skype client going offline once it is suspended. In fact any VoIP client on Windows Phone 8 will be allowed to work in the background.

And it is much [more metro-styled](http://bgr.com/2012/10/22/skype-windows-8-windows-phone-8-microsoft/) now and therefore much nicer :) .

Comment: "We have also temporarily disabled the People Hub integration", this explains why I felt the way I did. Thanks